# null sent expect file content in xhr request

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, filereader

i have to make a pure and light weight javascript/html5 function to upload files.

it's almost done but now when i select a file it will create a blank file at the server with the same name

i checked and see the `filereader` api cant access the file
please see the description below:

```
    function uploadFileViaXHR(file){
         var boundary = "-------boundary";
         var content = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
         content += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";';  
         content += 'filename="' + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + '"';  
         content += '\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n';  
         content += '\r\n';

         reader = new FileReader();
         reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

        content += reader.result;
        content += '\r\n--' + boundary + '--\r\n';
        console.log(content);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        onUploadBegin(elemId, xhr, file.name, file.size);
        $('#' + elemId).addClass('html5');

        xhr.upload.onabort = function(e) { onUploadAbort(elemId, e); };
        xhr.upload.onerror = function(e) { onUploadError(elemId, e); };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) { onUploadProgress(elemId, e); };
        xhr.onload = function(e) { onUploadComplete(elemId, e); };

        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        // pseudo standard fields.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", file.fileSize);
        xhr.sendAsBinary(content);
   }
```

this file local output is for `console.log`

```
---------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";filename="145792_748.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

null
---------boundary--
```

and at server side it make an empty file
also when i change this line : 
`content += reader.result;` to `content += reader;`

the local out put is

```
---------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";filename="145792_748.jpg"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

[object FileReader]
---------boundary--
```

and server make a file with content of `[object FileReader]` !!
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `FormData` instead of read file.

its more simple

also you can send external data `fd.append( 'field1', 'aaaa' );` with files too

```
function uploadFileViaXHR(file){

            fd = new FormData();
            fd.append( 'field1', 'aaaa' );
            fd.append( 'file', file );

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);

        onUploadBegin(elemId, xhr, file.name, file.size);
        $('#' + elemId).addClass('html5');

        xhr.upload.onabort = function(e) { onUploadAbort(elemId, e); };
        xhr.upload.onerror = function(e) { onUploadError(elemId, e); };
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) { onUploadProgress(elemId, e); };
        xhr.onload = function(e) { onUploadComplete(elemId, e); };

        xhr.send(fd);
}
```